# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01A8 on get_Address

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to search within excel file using method shown below, but I am getting error that says

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled Message:
>   Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01A8

on below line of code

```
if (currentRange.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1).Equals(startAddress))
```

**method**

```
    private void SearchResults(Excel.Range usedRange, string searchString, System.Data.DataTable dt)
    {
        Excel.Range startAddress = null;
        Excel.Range currentRange;

        currentRange = usedRange.Find(TB_First_Name.Text,
                                      Type.Missing,
                                      Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
                                      Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                                      Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                                      Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
                                      false,
                                      Type.Missing,
                                      Type.Missing);

        while (currentRange != null)
        {
            //Keep track of the first range you find.
            if (startAddress == null)
            {
                startAddress = currentRange;
            }
            //if current address is same as the starting address stop searching
            else if (currentRange.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1).Equals(startAddress))
            {
                break;
            }
            //keep searching for next value
            currentRange = usedRange.FindNext(currentRange);
            AddExcelRowToDataTable(usedRange, currentRange, dt);
        }
    }
```